# Show that $f=g$ when $\int_0^\varepsilon f dx = \int_0^\varepsilon g dx$ for all $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I know that this should be pretty straightforward to prove, but I'm trying to find a fairly clean proof for this.  I have one that seems to be far too complicated, and I'm wondering if this is actually easy to prove.

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$.  Show that if $\int_0^\varepsilon f \,dx = \int_0^\varepsilon g \,dx$ for all $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f=g$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$F(t) = \int_0^t f \, dx \quad \text{and} \quad G(t) = \int_0^t g \, dx$$ for $t \in \mathbb R$. You are given that $F = G$. What can you say about $F'$ and $G'$?

Comment: Thanks.  I was not thinking in this way because $f$ and $g$ aren't necessarily differentiable.  I guess there is a use for thinking about Statistics from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt=\int_0^x g(t)dt,\quad \forall x\in\Bbb R$$
so we differentiate:
$$F'(x)=f(x)=g(x),\quad \forall x\in\Bbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, and more elementary, method to the using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

Let $h=f-g$. We need to show $h$ is identically zero.

Note that $h$ is continuous and that $\int_0^x h(t)\,dt=0$ for all $x$. Show that this implies that $\int_a^b h(t)\,dt=0$ for any numbers $a,b$.  Now assume $h$ is not identically zero. Then by the continuity of $h$  there is an $\alpha>0$ and an interval $(a,b)$ such that either $h(x)>\alpha$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ or $h(x)<-\alpha$ for all $x\in(a,b)$. Consider now the integral $\int_a^b h(t)\,dt$ and derive a contradiction.